# Высота обертки равняется нулю

Tags: позиционирование, float, вёрстка, css

http://jsfiddle.net/hnEeq/

Помогите понять, почему wrapper имеет высоту 0. 
Заметил если сделать его плавающим то всё нормализуется. 
Я так понял как то связано с тем что элементы с float находятся внутри неплавающего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно поняли. Просто добавьте `<div style="clear: both"></div>` перед закрывающим тегом `#wrapper`.

[пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/hnEeq/1/)

[пруф с алертом высоты](http://jsfiddle.net/hnEeq/2/)

Comment: +1, но это не лучшая практика. Не стоит плодить лишние элементы, лучше использовать псевдо-элемент :before